# Using Workspace for different projects

Tags: java, eclipse, project

My new job requires to work with eclipse and the IDE works well so far. But there's one thing I couldn't manage / understand.  I am used to Visual Studio and there's a solution file containing some projects and the IDE enables me to work with them.

In eclipse I have my workspace and can add my projects. My projects may have some dependencies to each other and so on. Works great. But how to manage more than one projects ( or in the VS term solution)?

Do I have to use different workspaces? Ok, I can do that, but what if there's one project I want to use in two or more projects.

It's a beginner question, but an important one I think. So it should be interesting for other .NET users as well. Thanks a lot for helping.

Björn

Comment: Thumb rules I follow,

1) Keep all dependent projects in a dedicated work space.

2) If I end up with different non related projects in a single work space, I close the remaining project other than my working project.

Comment: Also, look at the Working Sets feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse you can add as many as projects you need based on your project dependencies.So now wen we are talking about the dependencies whether do you want add the .jar file or project.Both the ways will help you to get rid of compile errors in your project.

1.Add muiltiple projects just by importing your project

> File -> Import -> Select type of your project (Suggested options or i
>   use : Existing projects into workspace ,Existing maven projects)

2.You can link different projects by

> Right click the project in eclipse -> BuildPath ->Configure Build Path
>   -> Projects -> Add --> (locate your projects in the workspace).

3.You can package your existing project as .war or .jar and add them into your project by

> Right click the project in eclipse -> BuildPath ->Configure Build Path
>   -> Select libraries --> Add external jars (Then locate your jar's and add them).

Basically 2nd option is used in the debugging purpose,while the 3rd is bit tough to debug.

All these projects can be navigated using Project explorer window.